# How to fix "The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2_ttf.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I am trying to use sdl_ttf to display text in a window, but when I run my program, an error window pops up and says what the title says above. I have put SDL2_ttf.dll into the debug folder like I was supposed to during installation of ttf, so that cannot be the problem.

Comment: Make sure you put `SDL2_ttf.dll` into the folder and not `SDL2_ttf.dll.a` Windows explorer by default hides the last extension so be careful. I always turn that feature off.

Comment: Check if your program is 32-bit or 64-bit; it will need to have the same bitness as the DLL.

Comment: SDL_ttf.dll have dependencies on other dlls. `libfreetype-6.dll` and `zlib1.dll` are bundled with SDL_ttf. All of that must have correct architecture. You can verify dependency chain of your executable with http://dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the files were in the wrong folder. The tutorial said that I had to put them in the debug folder, while in reality I had to put them in the project directory.